# How do I do a LEFT join on INEQUALITY condition in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, left-join

I need to implement a left join on

`TABLE A: id(1,2,3); value(A,B,C)

 TABLE B: id(2,3); value(E,F)`

and write a join that gives me,

`TABLE C: A.id(1,2,3); B.id(NULL,NULL,2); A.value(A,B,C);  B.value(NULL,NULL,E)`

Comment: Can you represent your data in a table format?  I cannot figure out what the rows and columns look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is like this:

```
id  val
1    A
2    B
3    C
```

and this

```
id val
2  E
3  F
```

and you want

```
id  val1  id2  Val2
1    A    null null
2    B    2     E
3    C    null null
```

Then:

```
select a.id as aid, a.val as aval, b.id as bid, b.val as bval
from table1 a
 left outer join
 table2 b
 on a.id = b.id
 where b.id = 2;
```

Of course you condition on b.val = E or something else but you are not clear on that.

You could also do something like this:

```
select a.*, b.val as bval
from table1 a
left outer join
(Select * from table2 where id = 2) b
on a.id=bid;
```

Then you don't carry around an extra id that likely has no additional information.  You can condition table some other way there as well.  Again not sure if it is exactly what you need but good luck.

Comment: Once you add "where b.id = 2" you force an inner join

Comment: @iggy is correct, see bullet "Joins occur BEFORE WHERE CLAUSES" at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins